# Why is this code throwing NULL exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file

I have the following code where I am selecting a file. But no matter what file I select I get the following exception:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column ImgPath.

It seems like file is not passing any value back to controller, am I doing something wrong?

create.cshtml:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImgPath)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
</div>
```

Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(TopSong topsong, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //verify user has selected file
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(
                "~/Content/themes/base/images/Movie Images"), fileName);

            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        db.TopSongs.Add(topsong);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    ViewBag.DateId = new SelectList(db.TopDates, "DateId", "DateId", 
                                    topsong.DateId);

    return View(topsong);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never setting the ImgPath property on your top song object.  You have a label for it in your view, but that does not assign value.  If I read your code correctly, you are needing to store the image path in the database along with some other stuff, so you should just need to add one line:

```
topsong.ImgPath = path;
```

But as your code stands now, it looks like you are always going to be saving a top song, even if the user does not upload an image (your saving is outside of the if statement).  By refactoring your function and reducing nesting, this should do what you want it to do

```
public ActionResult Create(TopSong topsong, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       ViewBag.DateId = new SelectList(db.TopDates, "DateId", "DateId",                                  topsong.DateId);
         Return this.View(topsong);
    }

//verify user has selected file
    if (file == null || file.ContentLength == 0)
    {
         ViewBag.DateId = new SelectList(db.TopDates, "DateId", "DateId",                                  topsong.DateId);
         ModelState.AddModelError("file", "You must choose a file to upload.");
         Return this.View(topsong);
    }

    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    topsong.ImgPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/themes/base/images/Movie Images"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(topsong.ImgPath);
    db.TopSongs.Add(topsong);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");  
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, also i was missing this line in View that is why i was getting file null. @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })). If someone else gets same problem it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to add a hidden field for ImgPath. Only input fields (not labels) will not be passed to the controller when the form is submitted...

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Should i remove the label?

Comment: You can keep the label. But you also need to add a @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ImgPath)

Comment: I tried this:  <input type="file" name="file" />
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ImgPath) . But i think problem is not just with the label. When i debug file is always null.